# Can't "integrate" jBPM 5.4 into a Maven web app

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jbpm

I have been having trouble getting "jBPM integrated into a web app" while using Eclipse (Kepler).  As a test I am simply trying to replicate the code found in the jBPM Full Installer's evaluation sample into the template code produced by a Maven JavaEE6 Archetype.  I have noted my steps below so that the problem can be easily reproduced.

1) Add to the JBoss standalone.xml:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/jdbc/jbpm-ds" pool-name="jBPMDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
    <driver>h2</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>sa</user-name>
        <password>sa</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

2) JBoss Central > Maven Project > filter on "javaee6" (to create the "myservlet" Project):
    Archetype = jboss-javaee6-webapp
    Accept all defaults

3) Set src\main\resources\META-INF\persistencet.xml to contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
      <!-- If you are running in a production environment, add a managed 
         data source, the example data source is just for proofs of concept! -->
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

4) Add a jBPM Runtime by pointing at the \runtime folder from the jBPM Full Installer.

5) Select the jBPM Perspective, right click the myservlet Project > Convert to jBPM Project.

6) Add to the Deployment Assembly the Java Build Path Entries | jBPM Library.

7) In src\main\java\com\mycompany\mywebapp\controller add to (arbitrarily chosen) MemberRegistration.java (which was automatically created as part of the Project) the following which comes from the evaluation sample code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.drools.KnowledgeBase;
import org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilder;
import org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory;
import org.drools.builder.ResourceType;
import org.drools.io.ResourceFactory;
import org.drools.logger.KnowledgeRuntimeLogger;
import org.drools.logger.KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory;
import org.drools.runtime.StatefulKnowledgeSession;
import org.jbpm.process.workitem.wsht.HornetQHTWorkItemHandler;
```

8) In this same module, in register() add the following which also comes from the evaluation sample code:

```
 try {
    // load up the knowledge base
    KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("Evaluation.bpmn"), ResourceType.BPMN2);
    KnowledgeBase kbase = kbuilder.newKnowledgeBase();
    StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
    HornetQHTWorkItemHandler humanTaskHandler = new HornetQHTWorkItemHandler(ksession);
    humanTaskHandler.setIpAddress("127.0.0.1");
    humanTaskHandler.setPort(5153);
    ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Human Task", humanTaskHandler);
    KnowledgeRuntimeLogger logger = KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory.newThreadedFileLogger(ksession, "test", 1000);
    // start a new process instance
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("employee", "krisv");
    params.put("reason", "Yearly performance evaluation");
    ksession.startProcess("com.sample.evaluation", params);
    System.out.println("Process started ...");
    logger.close();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

Upon deploying along with the six jBPM WARs we get the error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS011470: Persistence unitName was not specified and there are 2 persistence unit definitions in application deployment "myservlet.war".  Either change the application to have only one persistence unit definition or specify the unitName for each reference to a persistence unit.

Can someone explain what this error means and how to eliminate it?

Thank you.
Al

Comment: so, do you have two persistence.xml files?

Comment: You wrote that your persistence xml file name is : "persistencet.xml". Is it a typo on SO or  your name is really like that?

Comment: Step 5 "5) Select the jBPM Perspective, right click the myservlet Project > Convert to jBPM Project." it's not really needed.. if you are relying on maven you don't need anything special in eclipse.

Comment: The title of the question is wrong, you should add I cannot integrate jbpm in a java ee 6 application, it's nothing to do with maven.. probably you don't need to point to the runtime library at all.. you only need to add the right dependencies to your pom.xml file.. It seems that you don't have a clear understanding about how maven works, am I right?

Comment: Thx all! There is only one persistence.xml (yes, a typo above) in my Project @ src\main\resources\META-INF and only one copy in the deployed folders @ jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\myservlet.war\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF.  Salaboy, would you please tell me how to get the Maven dependencies into the Project?  Thx!